# Database select error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, database, innodb

Database select error
its my problem and when I restart my mysql to fix this error this problem solve but after 30 minutes or after hours again this error happen again.

I put link here screenshot from ssh [putty] of errors what should i do? for what reason this happen?

```
tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log
120813 17:33:57 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120813 17:33:57 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120813 17:33:57  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120813 17:33:58 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 63473783633
120813 17:33:58 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 20. Created with MySQL 50092, now running 50516. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
120813 17:33:58 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 29
120813 17:33:58 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
120813 17:33:58 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.16'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. reinstall your mysql but idont recommend use **mysql_upgrade**
2. check user table in mysql db it seems it has missing column or row
3. Repair Corrupted Databases  use ***mysqlcheck -rA -u root -p***

Comment: reinstall was best way for me .....tanx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Run mysqlcheck, see here -- http://scottlinux.com/2012/06/09/use-mysqlcheck-to-optimize-and-repair-mysql-databases/

Also, check if your RAM/disks have no issues. Also, upgrade to the latest release of whatever version of MySQL you are running.

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently upgraded mysql, you may be missing some columns in the system tables or something just didn't upgrade correctly. take a look at [mysql_upgrade](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html). earlier versions of mysql, you'd have to use `mysql_fix_privilege_tables`. it was removed in 5.5 i believe.

don't forget to back up you database(s) before you do anything in your db.